# How do I integrate pygame game into flask webapp?

Tags: javascript, python, flask, pygame

I have several games using the Pygame library that I would like to add to my web app.

I have done some research online and not found any answers to achieve this.

Is there a way to do this? Or will i have to use javascript for games.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pygame doesn't support web.

It potentially could in the future, see https://github.com/pygame/pygame/issues/718.

If you want your games to work on browers you could use javascript, or even write games in an engine like Godot or Unity, which I believe support exporting to web formats.

Comment: and now it supports web with very few code modifications.You can use the pygbag packager   from https://pypi.org/project/pygbag  documentation https://pygame-web.github.io